# Create table using two dimensional array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, collections, multidimensional-array, viewmodel

How can I fill a table with items in a list collection(item: Year), using a two dimensional array? The list collection was populated by an external database using linq queries.

ViewModel

```
public class TableViewModel
{       
    public List<MovieViewModel> Movies { get; set; }        
    public MyViewModel[,] MovieValues { get; set; }   
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public string MovieValue { get; set; }        
}

 public class MovieViewModel 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }   
}
```

Controller

```
TableViewModel item;
item=new TableViewModel();  
var AllMuvees = from d in db.MoviesTable     
          orderby d.Id                                            
          group d by d.Rating into  M                          
          select M;

List<MovieViewModel> OldMovies;
foreach (var a in M.AllMuvees)
{
 OldMovies.Add(new MovieViewModel()
 { 
    Id = g.MovieId.ToString(),
    Name =g.MovieName,
    Year = g.MovieYear.ToString()
 });
}


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
 for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
    item.MovieValues[i, j] = new MyViewModel()
    { MovieValues = ***** 
(I need help here: I want to fill this with the Years from OldMovies)};      
   }
  }

 return View(item);
```

Comment: I absolutely don't understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: It's normal that you don't understand. The code posted by the OP hardly makes any sense. It's very far from something that could be considered as valid C#. Also he didn't show his domain models so we could only be guessing how they look like and what properties they contain. We can only hope that this question will be improved.

Comment: sorry same boat as the others, sounds like a drink fuelled night gone wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at ListViewItem and then populating a list view?

If not then you can easily use a list of arrays, or even populate it in a foreach loop like bellow?

```
foreach( var v in Muvees )
{ListViewItem movieToAdd = new ListViewItem();
 movieToAdd.Text = v.movieid; 
movieToAdd.SubItems.Add(v.rating); 
movieToAdd.SubItems.Add(v.movieName); 
listOfMovies.Items.Add( movieToAdd ).BackColor = Color.Green;}    //add colour just because you can
```

arrange subItems however your list is set out

then in the form just right click your List View in the form(listOfMovies) and add columns

Sorry if I've misunderstood the question but i think this is what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of 10x10 i,j?

You can get each MovieViewModel in OldMovies by list[index] and that index must be between 0 to OldMovies.Count.

```
for(int i = 0; i < OldMovies.Count; i++)
{
  var movie = OldMovies[i];
  //movie.Name
  //movie.Year
}
```